# What is the min and max input voltage range of a buck converter to maintain efficiency above 90%

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, buck, flyback, buck-boost

I want to design a stepdown converter from 72V lithium ion battery to 12V, 5A. I am torn between using a flyback converter and a buck converter. Which topology will give me maximum efficiency at that power level?

Comment: The datasheet usually  has some neat efficiency curves as a function of different parameters.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. datasheet of the chopper controllers?

Comment: Are you designing the converter from scratch? Or using some IC?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question only answerable by the datasheet.

Comment: Don't flyback converters have transformers ? If so, I suppose that adding a transformer to a DC/DC design will likely decrease efficiency.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I was looking for a suitable IC from texas instruments but no buck converter IC is rated for such an input range. The maximum is 48V

Comment: A flyback converter is only a buck-boost converter with galvanic isolation... As such I don't think you can have a better efficiency than a buck converter.

Comment: @Ben even with such a high input voltage?

Comment: Maybe a 2-stage design could give you better efficiency. IIRC having a nominal duty cycle of about 50% will yield better efficiency... I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Ben what do you mean by IIRC

Comment: IIRC = If I recall correctly

Comment: @Ben Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I am torn between using a flyback converter and a buck converter.
> Which topology will give me maximum efficiency at that power level?*

Without a shadow of doubt, a buck converter will provide superior efficiency compared to a flyback converter by nearly double figures of percentage points.
Here's a good benchmark ([LTC3810](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3810fc.pdf)) for consideration: -

[image]

Whatever device you go for, choose a synchronous converter i.e. one with a MOSFET (as per M2 above) instead of a diode.

Here's one ([LTC7810](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC7810.pdf)) that is slightly more efficient on a 70 volt power supply: -

[image]

It can produce 12 volts at 5 amps from a 72 volt supply at about 95% efficiency. Probably near to about as good as it gets realistically. It's also good at up to 140 volts too. It's even 90%+ efficient at load currents as low as 3 mA too! A really nice bit of kit.

> *What is the min and max input voltage range of a buck converter to
> maintain efficiency above 90%*

The graphs in the pictures above give you that answer. If you are going to build one of these, don't skimp any anything. You need a damn fine layout with extensive ground planes and star-point power feeds, top quality inductors and really decent MOSFETs. You might also need to add an external supply filter system to reduce EMI that might be passed back to other circuits sharing the 72 volt supply. They are awesome though. Good luck finding one from TI that gives you confidence in the data sheet. Maybe [this one](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5146.pdf?ts=1641936045010&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM5146) should be considered: -

[image]

Comment: Without a shadow of doubt, a buck converter will provide superior efficiency compared to a flyback converter by nearly double figures of percentage points. ? 

You mean like 95% for a buck vs 90% for a flyback?

Comment: Probably closer to 85% for many flyback converters but some may be a tad better. It's the transformer losses that hit it hard.

Comment: @Andy aka Thanks a lot.

Comment: TI has a [web tool](https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/switching-regulator?powerSupply=0) for designing switching power supplies. The LM5146 indeed is among the choices.

Comment: @CL. thank you for your advice